# Laravel / MySQL Using calculated alias column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Could someone please help with the code below. I am getting an error due to the coloumn ‘distance’ not exsisting even though I have defined it as...

```
public static function getByDistance($lat, $lng, $distance)
{
  $result = Auction::join('users', 'auctions.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('users.id', '( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) as distance'))
        ->where ('distance', '<', $distance)
        ->get();

return $result;    

}
```

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/942592/4732334

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Dropped this kind of comparison to an alias column some versions ago.

It just works for sorting and grouping and having.

You can use:

```php
whereRaw( '(SUBQUERY) < ?', ['distance' => $distance])
```

I recommend using coalesce for null values.

**Edit**

The other answer provided is valid too btw.

Answer (score 2):

HAVING can be used to compare the value of an alias.

```
having('distance', '<', $distance);
```