# How can I pass a previously declared DB::raw() column into a whereRaw() query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a laravel eloquent query that gets a users ID, and their distance from your own position

```
 $lat = Auth::user()->lat;
 $lon = Auth::user()->lon;

 $users = DB::table('users')
 ->select(DB::raw("id, ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat 
- abs(lat))*pi()/180/2),2)+COS($lat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(lat)*pi()/180)
 *POWER(SIN(($lon-lon)*pi()/180/2),2)))as distance))
->whereRaw("distance < $radius")
>paginate($this->takeResults);
```

The query works and calculates all the distances.  But then I cant query those distances.  Because passing 'distance' to the whereRaw() statement doesn't seem to carry over?

I get

```
Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'
```

Anyone know how I can do this otherwise?

All the other answers say to try HAVING instead of WHERE because its a MYSQL problem.  But when i try laravels havingRaw() it still doesnt work?

Comment: You can't use aliases in where clause

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942592/1457270) good answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `havingRaw()`

```
$lat = Auth::user()->lat;
$lon = Auth::user()->lon;

$users = DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw("id, ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat - abs(lat))*pi()/180/2),2)+COS($lat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(lat)*pi()/180)*POWER(SIN(($lon-lon)*pi()/180/2),2)))as distance"))
    ->havingRaw("'distance' < $radius")
    ->paginate($this->takeResults);
```

Comment: Still get "Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' "