# Use custom column in the where clause from multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am creating a custom column with an alias `searchColumn`, which  which should be used in the where clause. How is this possible?

```
  SELECT lgs.*,
       lg.*,
       Concat(Ifnull(lgs.beneficiaryfirstname, ''),
       Ifnull(lgs.beneficiarylastname, ''),
       Ifnull(lg.Name, '')) AS
       "searchColumn"
FROM   local_giveaways_submissions lgs
       INNER JOIN local_giveaways lg
               ON lg.giveawayid = lgs.giveawayid
       LEFT JOIN local_giveaways_partners lgp
              ON lgs.partnerid = lgp.partnerid
WHERE  "searchcolumn" LIKE '%asd%'
```

Update:
Do you guys think it's better to use concat_ws() for search?

```
CONCAT_WS(
    '%',
    CONCAT(lgs.FirstName,' ',lgs.LastName),
    lgs.EmailAddress,
    CONCAT(lgs.BeneficiaryFirstName,' ',lgs.BeneficiaryLastName),
    lg.Name,
    lgp.PartnerName
) AS "SearchColumn"
```

Comment: In MySQL you cannot refer to output expression alias in WHERE clause, But you may do this in HAVING clause (and GROUP BY not needed - MySQL extension). Alternatively you may use the expression instead of alias. But in this particular case you may use `WHERE lgs.beneficiarylastname LIKE '%asd%'` - both NULL and `''` does not match.

Comment: Sorry didn't want to put duplicate column there. Updated my code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Comment: Also, see CONCAT_WS()

Comment: And again - neither COALESCE nor IFNULL affects LIKE testing result. These functions are useful for data output but excess for data processing. While using in WHERE/HAVING (directly or indirectly) they "kills" possible index usage and degrades the performance.

Comment: @Akina see updated question. Do you suggest using concat_ws() ? Performance doesn't matter much here because the data is not so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot refer to the alias `searchColumn` in the `WHERE` clause at the same level of the query, as this alias is not yet available.  However, MySQL has overloaded the `HAVING` operator for this purpose:

```sql
SELECT lgs.*, lg.*,
   CONCAT(IFNULL(lgs.beneficiaryfirstname, ''),
   IFNULL(lgs.beneficiarylastname, ''),
   IFNULL(lgs.beneficiarylastname, '')) AS searchColumn
FROM local_giveaways_submissions lgs
INNER JOIN local_giveaways lg
    ON lg.giveawayid = lgs.giveawayid
LEFT JOIN local_giveaways_partners lgp
    ON lgs.partnerid = lgp.partnerid
HAVING
    searchcolumn LIKE '%asd%'     -- this is allowed in MySQL
```