# Laravel custom query field in model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Model called Post. In my DB I have fields like "views" and "likes".
I need to add a custom field to my SELECT request like "reactions" that do "views + likes".
Using Attributes is a bad idea because I need to use "reactions" in WHERE with pagination.

Here is the code I need to work

```
$posts = Post::where('reactions', '>', 100)->paginate();
```

How can I make auto added field "reactions" all my requests?

Comment: "I need to use "reactions" in WHERE" - so make it a DB column? If you don't want to calculate it make it a virtual column as sum of views and likes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use alias in WHERE clause.

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
> clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
> executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

Copied from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942592/23315766)

As pointed in the document, using HAVING instead may do the work. Make sure to give a read at this question too: [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having/18710763#18710763).

You may use in Laravel query builder like bellow:

```
$posts = Post::select(['*', DB::raw('(views + likes) as reactions')])
    ->having('reactions', '>', 100)
    ->paginate();
```

Comment: And how can I add something like Post::select(['*', DB::raw('(views + likes) as reactions')]) to exec it automaticly in every query?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78141283/23315766) answer is one way to exec in every query you need but I think best practice is to use [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#global-scopes) for every Post model query.

Answer (score 2):

to do this you need to make a static function in your model (or put it in a helper function)
In your Post Model.php

```
public static function withReactions()
{
    return static::select(['*', DB::raw('(views + likes) as reactions')]);
}
```

and use it anywhere

```
$posts = Post::withReactions()->having("reactions",'>',100)->paginate();
```